# What should be the Mach-O Type of a custom iPhone framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, linker, symbols

I'm trying to build an iPhone framework using [this tutorial](http://www.blackjaguarstudios.com/blog/programming/2012/11/22/xcode-45-creating-ios-framework-and-hold-my-hand-im-3-years-old) but when I'm building my test app (the app that will use the built framework), it comes up with an error:

```
duplicate symbol _objc_unretainedPointer in:
...
8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

On Terminal, I did an `nm` call on the framework's binary and it has the symbols of a normal Executable including `_main`/`_objc_unretainedPointer`/etc. No wonder the duplicate errors are there: the frameworks has its own Executable symbols and so does the test app.

My question is, what should have been the correct Mach-O type for the Framework so that it doesn't have the `_main`/etc symbols? And how should have it been added to the test app?

And... is the tutorial also in error?

What I've tried: I set the framework's Mach-O Type to Dynamic Library and it got rid of the `_main`/etc symbols and the test app builds fine, but when the test app is ran on the simulator, it has a `dyld: Library not loaded` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem and got the setup to work but it doesn't answer the title question though.

The problem is the tutorial in original question (tutorial A) was in error. It lacked a bundle target setting which I found in another [**tutorial**](http://codefriend.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html) (tutorial B).

```
Link With Standard Libraries = No
```

From tutorial A, it wasn't set so it was default to Yes. After going through tutorial B and I set this to No, the test app using the built framework compiled successfully and behaved as desired.

To answer the title question: the Mach-O type (at least for this case and for tutorials A & B) should be **Relocatable Object File**.